# How to have IF conditions within a mySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder if there is a way to have IF condition inside a mySQL query?
What I want to do is to avoid having multiple queries.

Here is my thinking:

```
SELECT company, color, stock FROM mytable

if color = 'blue' : WHERE company = 5
if color = 'red' : WHERE stock = 'yes'

AND status = 'available'

order by color ASC
```

Thank you

Comment: I have edited the above example in question

Comment: You want where (colour = blue and company = 5) or (colour = red and stock = yes) ? If not please explain what you do want.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the conditions in the `WHERE` clause combined with the operator OR:

```
SELECT company, color, stock 
FROM mytable
WHERE 
  (
    (company = 5 AND color = 'blue')
    OR
    (stock = 'yes' AND color = 'red')
  )
  AND status = 'available'
ORDER BY color ASC
```